# 100% sizing image inside div issue, unwanted space on left and right

Tags: html, margin

building a webpage, and i ran in to some trouble, so here´s whats going on,

Im building the page using the bootstrap´s grid, but only the grid.

ive made a staff page where i want 4 pictures side by side, with a small margin between each image, the pictures should squares with an aspect of 1:1

Heres my: html;

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <img src="img/product.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <img src="img/product.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <img src="img/product.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <img src="img/product.jpg">
```

The image inside the div is cropped in 1:1

and has the following css:

```
max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
```

Heres the problem, for some reason the image dosn't fill out the div, the image is centered with about one em space on each side which result in an unwanted margin between the images.

Also how do i place magin between the divs, without one of the divs jumps down, when each div is 20% of the width.

I dont have enough reputation to post images yet :/

Comment: tried img-responsive ?

Comment: Bootstrap adds an automatic padding to the left and right of each col. You need to override it by creating a class which defines the new desired padding on each side of the image.

Comment: Thanks alot kin there was an 15px padding on left and right, removed it and now its working ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: In your css create a class called `.nopadding` (or anything you want) assign the following values to it `padding-left:0; padding-right:0;` then add it to `<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopadding">`
play around with it til you get the desired result.